# How can i calculate how much time have been passed using DateTime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button click event that start an operation :

```
private void Diagnose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            processfinish = false;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            timerCount = 0;
            count = 0;
            countBack = 5;
            CreateZip.Enabled = false;
            DriverVerifier.Enabled = false;
            Diagnose.Enabled = false;
            Diagnose.Text = "PROCESSING PLEASE WAIT";
            if (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy == false)
            {
                this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            Logger.Write("***** OPERATION STARTED *****");
        }
```

And the completed event of the backgroundworker :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {  
                processfinish = true;
                Logger.Write("***** OPERATION ENDED *****");
        }
```

And the timer1 tick event that start to work when its getting to the completed event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            Diagnose.Text = "PROCESS HAS FINISHED" + "  " + countBack--;
            if (count == 6)
            {
                Diagnose.Text = "COLLECT INFORMATION";
                Diagnose.Enabled = true;
                CreateZip.Enabled = true;
                ViewLogFile.Enabled = true;
                DriverVerifier.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

I want in my Logger text file to see something like:

```
Logger.Write("Operation Time Was: " + timepassed);
```

And timepassed will show minutes and second for example:

Operation Times Was: 05:21

Comment: You can use a StopWatch object, just instantiate and start at the beginning and stop it and get the time at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). [`Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start.aspx) it to begin timing, [`Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop.aspx) it when you are done, and then get the [`Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) time and [format it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way (not the best since it isn't thread safe at all, so it won't work if you have 2 operations working at the same time)

Declare a private variable:

```
DateTime _start;
```

Then in your `Diagnose_Click` method, assign a value to it:

```
_start = DateTime.Now;
```

And in your `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` you can have the time elapsed like that:

```
TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - _start;
```

And you can write it directly in your log file using something like:

```
Logger.Write("Operation time was: " + elapsed.Minutes + "mn " + elapsed.Seconds + "s");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Then after you are done processing do

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

//This will give you something like 2hrs 15min or 15 days 11 hours 10 min ect
TimeSpan timePassed = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

Here is the MSDN Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx

The advantage to using this method (other than it specifically uses DateTime like you specified above) is that there is no timer running. You are not using any resources really here. You just grab the DateTime at the start of your process and at the end. Then subtract them to get the difference. To easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Create new stopwatch
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();
    // Do something
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    // Stop timing
    stopwatch.Stop();
    // Write result
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);
```