# Animate needle transition

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

When I read data from GPS sensor, it comes with a slight delay. You are not getting values like 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 etc, but they are coming like 1 then suddenly 5 or 9 or 12. In this case needle is jumping back and forth. Anybody have an idea how to make needle moving smoothly? I guess some kind of delay is needed?

Something like, taken from another control:

```
    async void animateProgress(int progress)
    {
        sweepAngle = 1;

        // Looping at data interval of 5
        for (int i = 0; i < progress; i=i+5)
        {
            sweepAngle = i;
            await Task.Delay(3);
        }
    }
```

However I am a bit confused how to implement that.

Here is code for drawing a needle on canvas:

```
    private void OnDrawNeedle()
    {
        using (var needlePath = new SKPath())
        {
            //first set up needle pointing towards 0 degrees (or 6 o'clock)
            var widthOffset = ScaleToSize(NeedleWidth / 2.0f);
            var needleOffset = ScaleToSize(NeedleOffset);
            var needleStart = _center.Y - needleOffset;
            var needleLength = ScaleToSize(NeedleLength);

            needlePath.MoveTo(_center.X - widthOffset, needleStart);
            needlePath.LineTo(_center.X + widthOffset, needleStart);
            needlePath.LineTo(_center.X, needleStart + needleLength);
            needlePath.LineTo(_center.X - widthOffset, needleStart);
            needlePath.Close();

            //then calculate needle position in degrees
            var needlePosition = StartAngle + ((Value - RangeStart) / (RangeEnd - RangeStart) * SweepAngle);

            //finally rotate needle to actual value
            needlePath.Transform(SKMatrix.CreateRotationDegrees(needlePosition, _center.X, _center.Y));

            using (var needlePaint = new SKPaint())
            {
                needlePaint.IsAntialias = true;
                needlePaint.Color = NeedleColor.ToSKColor();
                needlePaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
                _canvas.DrawPath(needlePath, needlePaint);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Still having hard times to understand the process.

Let's say I don't want to apply this filter for control but have it in ViewModel to filter value. I have a Class from where I am getting data, for example GPSTracker. GPSTracker provides speed value, then I am subscribing to EventListener in my HomeViewModel and want to filter incoming value.

Based on Adams answer:

Comment: Maybe as an idea. Dont react to the change itself, but with a given interval, like every 100ms build an average of the last 5 data and show this. Then the needle is updating with a fixed framerate, that makes it smooth, and the average smoothes the position even more.

Comment: @feal could you possibly describe it more. Basically I have tried to gradually increase needlePosition, but had no success so far. Do you mean that inside OnDrawNeedle create loop for calculating average and increase value?

Comment: According to your description, this issue was caused by the uneven data you got from the GPS sensor. How do you let the location data(X,Y) change？

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I have been using `Plugin.Geolocator;` NuGet package for geolocation tracking. I have been also testing with data coming over bluetooth from microcontroller and there is slight delay. I think some genius brain is needed to get this smooth transition working. I think I have tried all possible solutions came into my mind. There is this solution with loop and delay, it seems to be smoother but not so smooth yet for some reason. I guess feal's suggestion with calculating average is the way to go further. Just wondering how big delay there would be once average is received?

Comment: Here is solution with loop and delay: https://github.com/rgot-org/Xamarin-Forms-RadialGauge

Comment: @HiFo The small framerate can make the drawing smoother. And the delay time is the sum of all the frame's time. So how big delay time isn't important and the framerate is the key.

Comment: And just like you sayed, the value you get is uneven. So you can set a fixed `_value` and a fixed `_time`, and then set the delay time such as `var delaytime=(value2-value1)/_value*_time` `await Task.Delay(delaytime)`

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I just started to think... is it better to do it in control itself or in ViewModel create some kind of buffer aka list that will take for example 5 last values and then pass them to control? I have done all the other edits I wanted to do for this control, also with your help from my previous question with numbering, but can't understand how to do the smoothness 0_o still. Original repo seems to be not active anymore, as I can't contact the contributor. Are you interested to contribute, if I will create a new public repo with current control? Maybe some help for others as well

Comment: Has your probem been solved by Adam's answer?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I have been testing method I got yesterday, but I think I got something wrong as it is not working as expected. I will try today again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from a controls background, to mimic behavior of an analog device, you could use an exponential (aka low-pass) filter.

There are two types of low-pass filters you can use, depending on what type of behavior you want to see: a first-order or second-order filter. To put it in a nutshell, if your reading was steady at 0 then suddenly changed to 10 and held steady at 10 (a step change), the first order would slowly go to 10, never passing it, then remain at 10 whereas the second order would speed up its progress towards 10, pass it, then oscillate in towards 10.

The function for an exponential filter is simple:

```
public void Exp_Filt(ref double filtered_value, double source_value, double time_passed, double time_constant)
{
    if (time_passed > 0.0)
    {
        if (time_constant > 0.0)
        {
            source_value += (filtered_value - source_value) * Math.Exp(-time_passed / time_constant);
        }
        filtered_value = source_value;
    }
}
```

`filtered_value` is the filtered version of the source `source_value`, `time_passed` is how much time passed from the last time this function was called to filter `filtered_value`, and `time_constant` is the time constant of the filter (FYI, reacting to a step change, `filtered_value` will get 63% of the way towards `source_value` after `time_constant` time has passed and 99% when 5x have passed). The units of `filtered_value` will be the same as `source_value`. The units of `time_passed` and `time_constant` need to be the same, whether this be seconds, microseconds, or jiffy. Additionally, `time_passed` should be significantly smaller than `time_constant` at all times, otherwise the filter behavior will become non-deterministic. There are multiple ways to get the `time_passed`, such as `Stopwatch`, see [How can I calculate how much time have been passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000146/how-can-i-calculate-how-much-time-have-been-passed-using-datetime)

Before using the filter function, you would need to initialize the `filtered_value` and whatever you use to get `time_passed`. For this example, I will use `stopwatch`.

```
var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
double filtered_value, filtered_dot_value;
...
filtered_value = source_value;
filtered_dot_value = 0.0;
stopwatch.Start();
```

To use this function for a first-order filter, you would loop the following using a timer or something similar

```
double time_passed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
stopwatch.Restart();
Exp_Filt(ref filtered_value, source_value, time_passed, time_constant);
```

To use this function for a second-order filter, you would loop the following using a timer or something similar

```
double time_passed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
stopwatch.Restart();
if (time_passed > 0.0)
{
    double last_value = filtered_value;
    filtered_value += filtered_dot_value * time_passed;
    Exp_Filt(ref filtered_value, source_value, time_passed, time_constant);
    Exp_Filt(ref filtered_dot_value, (filtered_value - last_value) / time_passed, time_passed, dot_time_constant);
}
```

The second-order filter works by taking the first derivative of the first-order filtered value into account. Also, I would recommend making `time_constant < dot_time_constant` - to start, I would set `dot_time_constant = 2 * time_constant`

Personally, I would call this filter in a background thread controlled by a [threading timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0) and have `time_passed` a constant equal to the timer's period, but I will leave the implementation specifics up to you.

**EDIT:**

Below is example class to create first and second order filters. To operate the filter, I use a threading timer set to process every 100 milliseconds. Being that this timer is rather consistent, making time_passed constant, I optimized the filter equation by pre-calculating `Math.Exp(-time_passed / time_constant)` and not dividing/multiplying 'dot' term by time_passed.

For first-order filter, use `var filter = new ExpFilter(initial_value, time_constant)`. For second-order filter, use `var filter = new ExpFilter(initial_value, time_constant, dot_time_constant)`. Then, to read latest filtered value, call `double value = filter.Value`. To set value to filter towards, call `filter.Value = value`.

```
    public class ExpFilter : IDisposable
    {
        private double _input, _output, _dot;
        private readonly double _tc, _tc_dot;
        private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes first-order filter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">initial value of filter</param>
        /// <param name="time_constant">time constant of filter, in seconds</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="time_constant"/> must be positive</exception>
        public ExpFilter(double value, double time_constant)
        {
            // time constant must be positive
            if (time_constant <= 0.0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(time_constant));

            // initialize filter
            _output = _input = value;
            _dot = 0.0;

            // calculate gain from time constant
            _tc = CalcTC(time_constant);

            // disable second-order
            _tc_dot = -1.0;

            // start filter timer
            StartTimer();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes second-order filter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">initial value of filter</param>
        /// <param name="time_constant">time constant of primary filter, in seconds</param>
        /// <param name="dot_time_constant">time constant of secondary filter, in seconds</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="time_constant"/> and <paramref name="dot_time_constant"/> must be positive</exception>
        public ExpFilter(double value, double time_constant, double dot_time_constant)
        {
            // time constant must be positive
            if (time_constant <= 0.0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(time_constant));
            if (dot_time_constant <= 0.0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dot_time_constant));

            // initialize filter
            _output = _input = value;
            _dot = 0.0;

            // calculate gains from time constants
            _tc = CalcTC(time_constant);
            _tc_dot = CalcTC(dot_time_constant);

            // start filter timer
            StartTimer();
        }

        // the following two functions must share the same time period
        private double CalcTC(double time_constant)
        {
            // time period = 0.1 s (100 ms)
            return Math.Exp(-0.1 / time_constant);
        }
        private void StartTimer()
        {
            // time period = 100 ms
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Filter_Timer, this, 100, 100);
        }

        ~ExpFilter()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _timer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set filter value
        /// </summary>
        public double Value
        {
            get => _output;
            set => _input = value;
        }

        private static void Filter_Timer(object stateInfo)
        {
            var _filter = (ExpFilter)stateInfo;

            // get values
            double _input = _filter._input;
            double _output = _filter._output;
            double _dot = _filter._dot;

            // if second-order, adjust _output (no change if first-order as _dot = 0)
            // then use filter function to calculate new filter value
            _input += (_output + _dot - _input) * _filter._tc;
            _filter._output = _input;

            if (_filter._tc_dot >= 0.0)
            {
                // calculate second-order portion of filter
                _output = _input - _output;
                _output += (_dot - _output) * _filter._tc_dot;
                _filter._dot = _output;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will start to test it today or latest tomorrow!

Comment: I have been testing method I got yesterday, but it didn't function as expected. Need to give it a new try today after reading your answer. Basically I have tried to make it so, that I am passing two variables `double source_value, double time_constant` into method and it will return `filtered_value`

Comment: One thing to note, if you are using a threading timer, `Math.Exp(-time_passed / time_constant)` should be constant as you can use the timer period for `time_passed`. `time_constant` should be constant value, ideally five times the update period from the GPS sensor. Therefore, if the GPS sensor updates every 200ms, time_constant should be at least 1 second. Increasing `time_constant` will smooth it out more, at the cost of longer latency between GPS data and user output. In this case, 2nd-order is used to reduce latency.

Comment: Oh, I have just noticed you have made full working solution. I will test it today, but for that much of effort from your side, I have no other choice than give promised support from my side.

Comment: By the way, maybe stupid question, what would you say. Does it make sense to filter value in ViewModel or just add this functionality directly into Control itself?

Comment: I've seen it done both ways. Benefit of in ViewModel is you can adjust the time constants (and timer update rates) directly as needed for your data. The benefit of in Control is, knowing the repaint period you are using, you could tie your repaint to the update rate of the filter. If you put it in the control, I would recommend creating parameters to enable user to adjust behavior of filter (enable/disable, first/second-order, etc.) so control is user-friendly, enabling you to use it elsewhere in the future.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Was thinking the same, if it is done in control itself, add couple of BindableProperties to be able to set settings in XAML. Thank you for helping! It look's like community in Xamarin section is not that big in size. For me looks like React Native and Flutter are taking over based on tagged messages on SO. However for a guy with some C# experience, Xamarin is the easiest choice. Hope Xamarin will gain it's positions in the future. Thanks again for your support!

Comment: sorry for hesitating you again... I have been working on another part of my app. Now came back to needle animation issue and have been struggling to get this working. I don't get what I have done wrong. Maybe you have time to check it out in any chance? I can can put all together and push to github. Do you have profile there so I can share the repo with you?

Comment: I do have a github account. One question though: have you tried animating the needle using manual inputs (ex: textbox) to see if the needle itself behaves as you expect, even without animation?

Comment: I am pretty sure I have missed something in implementation logic. I will create a speedometer app once I will have a free time during upcoming days and push it to github. Will post details here. If you could then check in real case scenario, where I have went wrong... Thank you a million in advance!

Comment: Can do.... Over the weekend, I realized my class does not handle full-rotating needle, such as compass, properly, but it should not have any issues handling a speedometer. (I could post an update to my class to handle full-rotating needle, if you are interested.)

Comment: I don't think there is a need for full rotating needle like in compass scenario. I will start to work now on Xamarin.Forms app for Android/iOS. Will drop a link here once finished. I will include there everything already as I have done so far and make it as complete as possible.

Comment: I just got a chance to look through your code. I've never made Xamarin apps before, so this has been a learning experience for me as well. From what I'm reading, you need to call `InvalidateSurface()` within your `CircularGauge` class to get it to redraw the arrow. The issue is this needs to be called from the main thread. Thus, I'm not sure how to make arrow redraw itself when value changed in `ExpFilter` as this is done in another thread. Also, I don't see where you use `ExpFilter`.

Comment: `InvalidateSurface()` is related to SkiaSharp library and used to trigger view update. Also it should be async await probably to complete the previous task and transition. Whole control logic should be redone. I am currently working on it.